# Is it possible to encode (<em>asdf</em>) in python Textile?

Tags: python, markup, textile

I'm using [python Textile](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/textile) to store markup in the database.  I would like to yield the following HTML snippet:

```
(<em>asdf</em>)
```

The obvious doesn't get encoded:

```
(_asdf_)   ->   <p>(_asdf_)</p>
```

The following works, but yields an ugly space:

```
( _asdf_)   ->   <p>( <em>asdf</em>)
```

Am I missing something obvious or is this just not possible using python Textile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say if this is a bug or not; in the form on the [Textile website](http://textile.thresholdstate.com/), `(_foo_)` works as you want, but in the downloadable PHP implementation, it doesn't.

You should be able to do this:

```
([_asdf_])  ->  <p>(<em>asdf</em>)</p>
```

However, this doesn't work, which **is** a bug in py-textile.  You either need to use this:

```
(]_asdf_])
```

or patch textile.py by changing line 918 (in the `Textile.span()` method) to:

```
            (?:^|(?<=[\s>%(pnct)s])|([{[]))
```

(the difference is in the final group; the brackets are incorrectly reversed.)

You could also change the line to:

```
            (?:^|(?<=[\s>(%(pnct)s])|([{[]))
```

(note the added parenthesis) to get the behavior you desire for `(_foo_)`, <s>but I'm not sure if that would break anything else.</s>

---

Follow up: the [latest version of the PHP Textile class](http://code.google.com/p/textpattern/source/browse/development/4.x/textpattern/lib/classTextile.php?r=3250#688) does indeed make a similar change to the one I suggested.

Comment: Very complete answer.  Thanks!